# Why does the line-height of text behave differently on Windows/Android compared to iOS?

Tags: html, css, ios, windows, web

I was working on a web app and discovered an issue when I needed my h1 text ("Ice Cream") to be perfectly vertically centered next to the gift icon (orange color).

To make it clearer, I used colors. The main container (.container) has the color aquamarine, the icon container (.icon) is blue, the h1 container (.h1-container) is burlywood, and the h1 tag has a background-color: blueviolet.

Now, let's get back to the problem. On Windows/Android, I achieved my goal without any issues, but when I open my web app on iOS (regardless of the browser), the h1 text ("Helado") changes its position, appearing a few pixels lower.

**Windows/android:**

[image]

**iOS:**

[image]

I found that this is due to the line-height of the text. On Windows/Android, the line-height (which I marked in purple) with a value of 26px causes the h1 text (with a font-size of 36px) to be positioned at the top, even going slightly beyond. On the other hand, on iOS, the same h1 text (with the same properties) is positioned at the bottom, going slightly beyond.

What I want is for the vertical position of the h1 to be the same on both Windows/Android and iOS, so that the text is vertically centered next to the icon.

This is how I structured my HTML and the styles they have:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.container .icon {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #0094FF;
}

.icon img {
  width: 15px;
}

.container .h1-container {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.h1-container h1 {
  font-family: 'Causten Round';
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 26px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="/gift-card.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="h1-container">
    <h1>Helado</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```